# Failed Serenity BDD Cucumber tests take long time to exit

Tags: java, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

In our Serenity BDD Cucumber test reports we notice failing test steps are taking over 1200secs to timeout/exit.

For example if a test hits a problem, such as;

`net.thucydides.core.pages.WrongPageError`

then the Serenity Report shows the test is taking 1200 seconds to exit. The tests are being run on Selenium Hub.

Is there a Serenity configuration parameter that controls timeout or are there any known issues when running via selenium hub that would cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was traced to the browserTimeout parameter in the grid config.